# Ingress doesn't route to service on EKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I'm trying to run ingress on EKS, such that when you enter to the website, with prefix `/dc` (i.e. `abc.com/dc`), it will route to the `dc-svc` service.
But for some reason when I enter to `/dc`, I get `404: Not Found`.

The service (`dc-svc`) is NodePort, but when I changed it to `LoadBalancer`, I could enter to the deployment via the LoadBalancer link, so I think its only problem with the ingress.

This is the yamls:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: abc-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs: 0.0.0.0/0
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: abc.com, www.abc.com
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
     - abc.com
     - www.abc.com
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /dc
        backend:
          serviceName: dc-svc
          servicePort: 9090
  - host: abc.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: abc-svc
          servicePort: 8000
  - host: www.abc.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: abc-svc
          servicePort: 8000
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dc-svc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: dc
  ports:
  - port: 9090
    name: "serving-dc"
    targetPort: 8080
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: dc-deployment
  name: dc
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dc
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dc-container
        image: docker.io/image:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Comment: You have installed the Load Balancer Controller? https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller

Comment: The ingress itself works for root website (i.e. `abc.com`), just not for other prefixes. So the ingress is installed properly.

Comment: Did you try to define ports for HTTP as you have done for HTTPS ? Look at the annotation:

    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]' 
Add also annotation `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance`

 Also try to add   alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo in the ingress configuration.
The "http", and the "host" should both be in the same section.

Instead of:

```
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /dc
        backend:
          serviceName: dc-svc
          servicePort: 9090
  - host: abc.com
```

Use

```
  - host: abc.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /dc
        backend:
          serviceName: dc-svc
          servicePort: 9090
```